Can't install C compiler
Trying to start learning C programming language, I'm stuck just at the beginning.
I'm following these instructions: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw
When entering this line in Msys2
pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-toolchain

I get the following:
error: clangarm64: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
:: Import PGP key 5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57? [Y/n]

After entering "Y" and waiting for about 30 minutes I get this response:
error: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" could not be looked up remotely

Have tried reinstalling Msys2 and googling for solutions, but nothings helped. Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

If you are on Windows, you should consider to use Visual Studio Community as a complete IDE instead. It's much more friendly for beginners.

Is there any reason you are trying to use mingw rather than the standard compiler?

https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/2397

@OldBoy, I actually just follow a beginner's guide and try to do as instructed for VS Code. What is a standard compiler?

I suggest you throw that beginners guide in the trash. Go to Visual Studio Community, and download the latest version. You can then use it to intall the Microsoft C compiler which is much easier to use in Windows. Then get yourself a copy of The C Programming Language from Amazon, which will teach you C in a clear structured manner.

Is this a fresh msys2 installation? Did you disable your antivirus software?

First install msys2-keyring package.
pacman -Sy msys2-keyring

then try to install other packages. If problem remains:
pacman-key add 5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57


Installing the Visual Studio Community edition is a much better idea.

It's a matter of choice. I prefer msys2 for its greate collection of packages and its comfortable unixish shell. I prefer gcc and clang to the msc compiler. I think there has a possibility to install clang, i dont know.

That may well be true for an experienced person, but not so much for a beginner trying to learn the language.

I wouldn't recommend manually adding the key, without first confirming the key is legit.

I get the same error after inputting "pacman -Sy msys2-keyring"
